# How to get all the field and value of node as an array?

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

I am trying to render all field and value of a node as an array dynamically. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`Entity::toArray()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AtoArray/8.5.x):

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1);
print_r($node->toArray());
```